# Regular expression where part of string must be number between 0-100

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

I need to validate serial numbers.  For this we use regular expressions in C#, and a certain product, part of the serial number is the "seconds since midnight".  There are 86400 seconds in a day, but how can I validate it as a 5-digit number in this string?:

```
654984051-86400-231324
```

I can't use this concept:

```
[0-8][0-6][0-4][0-0][0-0]
```

Because then `86399` wouldn't be valid.  How can I overcome this?  I want something like:

```
[00000-86400]
```

**UPDATE**
I want to make it clear that I'm aware of - and agree with - the *"don't use regular expressions when there's a simpler way"* school-of-thought.  [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909528/regular-expression-where-part-of-string-must-be-number-between-0-100#1909559) is exactly how I'd like to do it, however this serial number validation is for all serial numbers that pass through our system - there's currently no custom validation code for these specific ones.  *In this case* I have a good reason for looking for a regex solution.

Of course, if there isn't one, then that makes the case for custom validation for these particular products undeniable, but I wanted to explore this avenue fully before going with a solution that requires code changes.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.  -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Not really true, but i can't seem to remember the blog post i read about it. Still a good quote...

Comment: @benjamin I'm not one of those people, I actually made a sound and reasonable decision to pursure regexes *in this case*.  I'd really rather not use them, but if there was one that worked, it would be a config change.  If there isn't, and I need to write custom validation code, then that's higher impact to our system and carries much more overhead.

Comment: If regular expressions are your only tool, you might consider not tagging your question with `c#` in that case.

Comment: Hey Neil, I think a regex is a good idea.  However, it really only fits one half of your problem well.  I think Jason's answer uses both well.  Validating that a number is less than another with regexes is way more effort than it's worth.  Use a regex for what it's good for and use an if statement for what it's good for.

Comment: Just understood what you meant by "code changes", etc.  I've worked on what some people call "legacy" systems before, so I think I know what you mean.  It does make it a hard choice...  I'm tempted to say that making such a regular expression would be a good compromise, but I'd hate to have to be the "next guy" who has to figure it out when there's a bug.  Is it really a huge change to add this validation logic?  Doing it regex-only seems like something that will be regretted later.

Comment: @Greg: Yes, I wondered about the C# tag, too.  I went for it in the end because I'm aware there are different flavours of regex, and didn't want to confuse the issue if Java regexes were slightly different etc.

Comment: @Benjamin: It's not a massive code change, really.  The cost is the fact that it would mean a new build, which will need testing and deployment, and we'd still need config changes so that we can set which products need to use this custom C# validation as well as a basic regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Generate a Regular Expression to Match an Arbitrary Numeric Range** 
http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

yields the following regex expression:

```
\b0*([0-9]{1,4}|[1-7][0-9]{4}|8[0-5][0-9]{3}|86[0-3][0-9]{2}|86400)\b
```

Description of output:

```
First, break into equal length ranges:
  0 - 9
  10 - 99
  100 - 999
  1000 - 9999
  10000 - 86400

Second, break into ranges that yield simple regexes:
  0 - 9
  10 - 99
  100 - 999
  1000 - 9999
  10000 - 79999
  80000 - 85999
  86000 - 86399
  86400 - 86400

Turn each range into a regex:
  [0-9]
  [1-9][0-9]
  [1-9][0-9]{2}
  [1-9][0-9]{3}
  [1-7][0-9]{4}
  8[0-5][0-9]{3}
  86[0-3][0-9]{2}
  86400

Collapse adjacent powers of 10:
  [0-9]{1,4}
  [1-7][0-9]{4}
  8[0-5][0-9]{3}
  86[0-3][0-9]{2}
  86400

Combining the regexes above yields:
  0*([0-9]{1,4}|[1-7][0-9]{4}|8[0-5][0-9]{3}|86[0-3][0-9]{2}|86400)
```

Tested here:
http://osteele.com/tools/rework/

Answer (score 10):

Don't use regex? If you're struggling to come up with the regex to parse this that says that maybe it's too complex and you should find something simpler. I see absolutely no benefit to using regex here when a simple

```
int value;
if(!Int32.TryParse(s, out value)) {
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
if(value < 0 || value > 86400) {
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

will work just fine. It's just so clear and easily maintainable.

Comment: Regex is a great, powerful tool but I think people reach for it way too often and too quickly anytime a parsing/validation problem comes up.

Comment: Whoa, hold your horses - this serial number validation is for all serial numbers that pass through our system - there's no custom validation code for these specific ones.  I know to avoid regex if possible, but there are good reasons for it *in this case*.

Comment: That sounds like a great reason to add hooks to your system.

Answer (score 7):

You don't want to try to use regular expressions for this, you'll end up with something incomprehensible, unwieldy, and difficult to modify (somebody will probably suggest one :). What you want to do is match the string using a regex to make sure that it contains digits in the *format* you want, then pull out a matching group and check the range using an arithmetic comparison. For example, in pseudocode:

```
match regex /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/
serial = capture group 2
if serial >= 0 and serial <= 86400 then
    // serial is valid
end if
```

Answer (score 6):

With the standard 'this-is-not-a-particularly-regexy-problem' caveat,

```
[0-7]\d{4}|8[0-5]\d{3}|86[0-3]\d{2}|86400
```

Comment: Robert Harvey's version also handles numbers under 10000 that aren't 0-padded.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a pure regex solution I believe this would work although the other posters make a good point about only validating they are digits and then using a matching group to validate the actual number.

```
([0-7][0-9]{4}) | (8[0-5][0-9]{3}) | (86[0-3][0-9]{2}) | (86400)
```

Comment: Third times a charm hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex combined with some .NET code to accomplish this.  A pure regex solution isn't going to be easy or efficient to handle large number ranges.

But this will:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"\d{9}-(\d{5})-\d{6}");
String value = myRegex.Replace(@"654984051-86400-231324", "$1");
```

This will grab the value 86400 in this case.  And then you'd just check if the captured number is between 0 and 86400 as per Jason's answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is possible in regular expressions since this isn't something that can be checked as part of a regular language.  In other words, a finite state automata machine cannot recognize this string so a regular expression cannot either.

Edit: This can be recognized by a regex, but not in an elegant way.  It would require a monster *or* chain (e.g.: `00000|00001|00002` or `0{1,5}|0{1,4}1|0{1,4}2`).  To me, having to enumerate such a large set of possibilities makes it clear that while it is technically possible, it is not feasible or manageable.

Comment: is this true? I don't really know much about FSA, but the hypothetical counterexample is "00000|00001|... .... |86400"

Comment: It certainly can, because the string representations of every whole number between 0 and 86400 is a finite set. All finite sets can be accepted by a finite-state automaton.

Comment: You're both definitely right about my omission. I've edited my answer

Comment: It is feasible in an "elegant" manner by generating the regex programatically... But that would be taking the problem statement upside down... Anyway, as per consensus, RegEx is definitely not appropriate got this type of use cases.

Comment: Generating a 518399 character string is not exactly what I would call elegant and it seems to me that it would be very inefficient to parse and compare against.

Comment: See Jimmy's answer - it's a regex that matches the problem definition, and is only 41 characters long, not 518399...

Comment: True, but that's also not generating the regex programmatically, which is what the 518399 was in reference to.