# Regular Expression - Only number from X to Y

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression where part of string must be number between 0-100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909528/regular-expression-where-part-of-string-must-be-number-between-0-100)

I'd like to know how to filter a variable that must be only numbers and from 1 to 300 by using regular expression on PHP. How can I do it?

P.S. I can't really find a good manual with definition of each symbol about regex. For example, what does it mean **/^** or **+$/i**??

Comment: When you ask about Regex, always specify the language you are using. A good link about Regex is www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: $number > 0 && $number <= 300 isn't good enough? Unless you have a real good reason to use regex for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that -- this can become overly complicated. Just break out the number from the string, convert it to integer (if you like to) and check its value:

```
function match( $n ) {
  preg_match( '(\d+)', $n, $matches );
  return $matches && $matches[ 0 ] >= 1 && $matches[ 0 ] <= 300;
}
```

Comment: Why I should convert it? if its a string, it return false...else it check it...

Comment: @markzzz: PHP does some automatic type conversion. If you'd like to have more control over what's happening, you won't rely on that. In this case that should not be necessary.

Answer (score 6):

```
([1-9][0-9]?|[12][0-9][0-9]|300)
```

In other words, either (`|`) match a number from 1 to 9 (`[1-9]`), from 10 to 99 (`[1-9][0-9]?`), from 100 to 299 (`[12][0-9][0-9]`), or 300.

#### See:

- [Regular Expressions Reference -
  Basic Syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)
- [Regex Tutorial - Start of String and End of String Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: Hmm, this matches `3000` as well, doesn't it?

Comment: Ok, you did not specify the usage of your regex -- I just assumed `preg_match`, which does not work apparently.