# Regular Expression for a Positive Number between 0 and 12

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I've tried with no luck to search the interwebs for a regular expression that checks for:

- A positive #
- Between 0 and 12

I need to put it in the brackets for this particular line of code

```
 Regex rxValidHeightInches = new Regex();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression where part of string must be number between 0-100](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909528/regular-expression-where-part-of-string-must-be-number-between-0-100)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work `^(\d|(1[0-2]))$`

```
var rxValidHeightInches = new Regex("^(\\d|(1[0-2]))$");
```

Comment: assuming you mean between as in "inclusive"

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
(?<!-)(\b((1[01])|[1-9])\b)
```

It matches `1 - 9` or `10` or `11`. Negative numbers are always excluded.

**Explaination**

```
-Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind) «(?<!-)»
---Match the character “-” literally «-»
-Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\b((1[01])|[1-9])\b)»
---Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
---Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «((1[01])|[1-9])»
------Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(1[01])»
---------Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(1[01])»
------------Match the character “1” literally «1»
------------Match a single character present in the list “01” «[01]»
------Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[1-9]»
---------Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]»
---Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

---

**This one includes 0 - 12**

```
(?<!-)(\b((1[0-2])|[0-9])\b)
```

[image]